# CMake script for STM32 CubeMX not linking correctly

Tags: c++, cmake, stm32, openocd, cubemx

I am trying to write a CMake script to link the files generated by CubeMX as a library to an executable. So far, once I move the variable ${SOURCES} containing all the CubeMX sources to out of the executable and only linke against the library, the program breaks. There are no errors, no issue in transfer, only the program does not execute correctly. If I compile the executable with ${SOURCES} in `add_executable()` everything works. Any ideas on how to solve this problem or at least further track it down?

Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```cpp
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

# specify cross-compilers and tools
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_AR arm-none-eabi-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set(SIZE arm-none-eabi-size)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# project settings
project(F439CMake C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

#Uncomment for hardware floating point
#add_compile_definitions(ARM_MATH_CM4;ARM_MATH_MATRIX_CHECK;ARM_MATH_ROUNDING)
#add_compile_options(-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16)
#add_link_options(-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16)

#Uncomment for software floating point
#add_compile_options(-mfloat-abi=soft)

add_compile_options(-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork)
add_compile_options(-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -fmessage-length=0)

# uncomment to mitigate c++17 absolute addresses warnings
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-register")

# Enable assembler files preprocessing
add_compile_options($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM>:-x$<SEMICOLON>assembler-with-cpp>)

if ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Release")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "RelWithDebInfo")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast -g)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for size")
    add_compile_options(-Os)
else ()
    message(STATUS "Minimal optimization, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Og -g)
endif ()

include_directories(Core/Inc Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include Drivers/CMSIS/Include)

add_definitions(-DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F439xx)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "Core/*.*" "Drivers/*.*")

set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F439ZITX_FLASH.ld)

add_link_options(-Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map)
add_link_options(-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork)
add_link_options(-T ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

add_library(CUBEMX STATIC ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Core/Src/main.c ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC CUBEMX)

set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".elf")

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE}
Building ${BIN_FILE}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to pinpoint the issue without having access to any errors, so here are my tips on how you can solve this problem.

1. I don't see startup script mentioned anywhere in your cmake. It should be the part of the main executable. Try appending it manually to executable target together with `main.c`.
2. To make sure everything is actually compiling the way it should, you should enable as many warnings as possible. I suggest starting with `-Wall -Wall -Wpedantic`.
3. `add_definitions` is depracated. You should use alternatives, as it is really easy to mess up compiler arguments with this one.
4. Try to avoid global settings in CMake. Prefer commands that take specific target (they all start with `target_` prefix).
5. Try moving toolchain specific setting to a toolchain file. While I can't that this will solve your problem, in the past setting compiler setting in main CMake lead to many problems. [Cross Compiling with CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html)
6. Try using known working example of CMake project( [I like this one](https://github.com/MaJerle/stm32-cube-cmake-vscode)) and only then apply changes.